# Implementing my own incremental search

Tags: keymap, isearch

What would be the best way to implement an Emacs Lisp command that pops up the minibuffer, lets the user edit a search string there, and runs code to update the search results after each keystroke (or other command) that changes the minibuffer contents? To be specific, I'm asking about how to run a Lisp function in response to text changes; running a Lisp function in response to each keystroke may be close enough.

I'm talking about something that resembles the well-known incremental search (I-search) commands built into Emacs. `isearch.el` shows that I-search itself sets up `isearch-mode-map` such that each ASCII/multibyte character is manually mapped onto the `isearch-printing-char` command. (It loops over all the numerical character codepoints and assigns the same command to each codepoint).

If possible, it would probably be easier to have normal minibuffer editing, and simply have a hook function that gets called after every keystroke (or other command) that changes the minibuffer contents.

Comment: Add a buffer-local `post-command-hook` when you set up the minibuffer?

Comment: The question is far too broad. What is it, specifically, that you are really trying to do. Saying "why" might make clearer what you're looking for, what problem you're trying to solve or what missing feature you want to implement.

Comment: [FYI: Emacs Isearch doesn't use the minibuffer (except if you use `M-e` to edit the search string). It uses the echo area, but with the cursor in that area. It can seem like it's using the minibuffer, but it's not.]

Comment: Thanks. I reworded the question to emphasize that I'm looking for a way (or ways) to run code in response to text changes in the input area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minibuffer is a normal buffer, so you can use `post-command-hook` or `after-change-functions` (or both) to react to edits.  You can use `minibuffer-with-setup-hook` to set them up:

```
(minibuffer-with-setup-hook
    (lambda ()
      (add-hook 'post-command-hook #'my-minibuf-after-cmd nil 'local)
      (add-hook 'after-change-functions #'my-minibuf-after-edit nil 'local))
  (read-string ...))
```

Using both can be useful: it's often a good idea to limit the amount of code run in `after-change-functions` either for performance reasons (a single command (such as filling a paragraph) can sometimes cause thousands of individual changes) or to avoid undesired interactions (`after-change-functions` is run right when the change takes place, before the command is finished, so it might run in an unusual context). In constrast `post-command-hook` is only run once per user interaction and "at top-level", so it is customary to limit `after-change-functions` to record the change in some global variable, and then use that var in `post-command-hook`.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I ended up going with `after-change-functions` only.

Comment: Tip to anyone implementing incremental narrowing: use a custom invisibility spec. See the _Invisible Text_ section in the Emacs Lisp Reference Manual for details.

Comment: Also `(with-selected-window ...)` and `(recenter 0)` can reset the display to the top of the buffer after each update to the search results.